# Spreading symbols with sequence before transmission

Tags: digital-communications

I  have been learning IEEE 802.11ad and the following processing algorithm

I was wondering what is the need for spreading with Golay sequence. I am guessing it has to with something like spread spectrum in CDMA applications.

Does anyone know why and whats the purpose of using such a block after modulation block?

Thanks

Comment: Is this your source: http://cdn.rohde-schwarz.com/pws/dl_downloads/dl_application/application_notes/1ma220/1MA220_1e_WLAN_11ad_WP.pdf ? Mind including it in your question?

Comment: sure i will include reference.

Comment: @deve the reference is included. Mind me asking how were you able to find it!

Comment: I googled "IEEE 802.11ad" and this was one of the first results ;) Btw, why did you remove the hint that the block diagram is from 802.11ad? I think this is helpful for answering the question.

Comment: Ok I thought it was irreleavant. I will add again.

Comment: As you noted, yes, the function of the "spreader" is to implement spread spectrum. A better way to phrase the question might be "why is direct-sequence spread spectrum used in 802.11ad?" I don't know the rationale, but I'm sure there is one. From a quick read of that paper, I don't think it has anything to do with CDMA, as there doesn't seem to be provision for using different codes for different users. The increased bandwidth after spreading can make it easier to track symbol timing accurately; perhaps it's related to that.

Comment: Thanks. I agree I believe its not for CDMA purposes. Just wondering why multiply the sequence with Golay sequence (I suppose its has high chip rate) and spreads the spectrum of information sequence.

Comment: On another note, does spreading mitigate ISI? @Deve

Comment: It can mitigate ISI somewhat. The autocorrelation function of the spread-spectrum waveform will be much narrower in time, so multipath delays that are a fraction of a symbol period can occur without falling on top of the signal of interest at the correct sampling instants.

Comment: @JasonR I need to ask one more question, why is that when we increase the transmitted signal bandwidth, tracking the symbol timing is easier? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just the control channel that is spread.  It appears that it is spread primarily to make the signal more robust in the face of frequency selective fading, which is probably a major problem at 60 GHz.  It is easy to use spreading to get the robustness because the data rate of the control channel is low.  In other words, the spreading is fulfilling two roles: converting the low control channel data rate to the high OFDM symbol rate, and increasing the control channel's robustness.

Comment: Thanks, so when we spread the spectrum of information signal, do we increase the data rate? I thought with spreading the rates decrease and thus more reliable. The reason I am asking is because you mentioned that we are coverting a low data rate to high OFDM data rate. Are usually higer rates achieved with spreading the spectrum?

Comment: Sorry, poor use of terminology.  Spreading increases the symbol (or chip) rate, not the data rate.  Will edit the answer.

Comment: thanks, which makes me think, does it increase of decrease the data rates?

Comment: Spreading doesn't change the data rate at all.

Comment: but in your answer you mentioned  that we convert the low control channel data rate to high OFDM symbol rate, I dont understnad what you meant by this...i.e. how did we end up with OFDM